# Why iOS SDK does not encapsulate all of its library data members?

Tags: ios, swift

In the world of Java and Android almost class has getters and setters to access and mutate its data members.

However, in Swift and iOS development I see a pattern of development that is different than what I am used to.

iOS SDK tends to allow access and mutation directly to many of its data members (properties).

Example in Java and Android:

```
textView.setText("Android Development");

String aText = textView.getText();
```

Example in Swift and iOS:

```
label.text = ""
let aText = label.text
```

As you can see, iOS SDK provides direct access to its properties.

Comment: Ask this question to `iOS developer.` and Why `android` tag here?

Comment: I develop for iOS now, but I want to know the difference in terms of standards or patterns or even best practice. You are right I have to remove `Android` and `Java` tags.

Comment: The default programming language for `Android` is `JAVA`. and Search `the difference in terms of standards or patterns or even best practice in Google`. for better answer.

Comment: After developing for iOS, I feel like its is better to have direct access in some situation where the set and get method are just setting/returning the value in one line.

Comment: It's a different programming language so has different paradigm. Just is so!
Read more about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in your example. In second case (swift code) will be called methods `func setText(text: String)` and `func text() -> String`

This is only a sugar for developers.
Read please about [properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) in swift or objective-c.

Each property (that has readwrite permissions) create two methods: one for setting and one for getting data. So practically there is no difference in you code.